# My Kafka Consumer windows service remains in "Starting" status, although I get no unhandled exception from my code. The service seems to run partialy

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a C# Windows service Kafka consumer based on Confluent Kafka library that is reading the values from a Kafka topic and writes to a file. When I start the windows service it is always remaining in "Starting" status. But on the other side I see that values are written to the target file , but not in that frequency, that was required (as 1 second). Additionaly the data that is written to the file is not the actual data, but always 30-40 seconds from the past.
It seems that the service is running "partialy" and with delay.(although it is not in "running" status. How is that possible?

I have restarted the service several times but always the same. There seems nothing strange on the Kafka side, there are hundreds of topics that can be consumed without problem.
I have also started my server. I get also no exception from my code. What could be the problem?

My code:

```
public void Read_from_Kafka()
    {
        try
        {

           using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(error_log))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Start Kafka2 " + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }

            var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                BootstrapServers = "XXXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXX:XXXX",
                GroupId = "foo",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
                SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl,
                SslCaLocation = "C:\\Cert\\Kafka\\BOSCH-CA-DE.pem",
                SslCertificateLocation = "C:\\Cert\\Kafka\\TEF4.cert.pem",
                SslKeyLocation = "C:\\cert\\Kafka\\TEF4.key.pem",
                SslKeyPassword = "TEF4",
                EnableAutoCommit = false


            };

            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;

            using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
            {
                consumer.Subscribe("TOPIC_NAME");     

                while (var_true)
                {
                    var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);
                    Kafka_message_total = consumeResult.Message.Value;
                    
                    Write_Tag_Values_to_File();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                }

                consumer.Close();
            }
         }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(error_log))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Kafka Read Error: " + ex + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more logs for debugging? For example is the Consume function blocking and timing out? Could you print anything within the while loop to see that it is working? And you're not seeing anything in your error log file?